# What is the value of $\frac{d\alpha}{dt} $?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, improper-integrals

The following question was asked in an exam:
 Given $\alpha $=$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac {dt}{1+t^2}} $.
Then is $\frac {d\alpha}{dt} $=$\frac{1}{1+t^2}$?
I know that the value $\alpha$=$\frac {\pi}{2} $. So as $\alpha $ is a constant, it's derivative is 0. Am I correct?

Comment: Surely yes! {}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Yep! Am sorry! Post edited....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the question is silly. But anyway, you are right. And the fact that $\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}=\frac\pi2$ is not important. The only thing that matters is that $\alpha$ is constant.

Comment: The error $\frac{d\alpha}{dt} = \frac{1}{1+t^2}$ is common among beginners.  So the question is not silly.